# Giving a std::shared_ptr<std::thread> to itself. Defined or Undefined behavior

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, shared-ptr

I have te following code:

```
void launchThread() {
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> t;
    t = std::make_shared<std::thread>([t] {std::cout<< "HelloWorld"<<std::endl;});
    t->detach();
}

int main(){
    launchThread();
    somthing that takes a while.... 
}
```

If I'm correct the thead should keep itself alive using the shared pointer till the thread itself runs out of scope. But I wonder what happens when the shared pointer gets destructed, will the thread be cleaned properly? Or is this bad practice?

Comment: The assignment to `t` occurs after its value has been captured by the lambda object. If you look at `t.get()` in the thread it will be null.

Comment: What is the point of `[t] {`? What are you trying to do and why do you believe that code might work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::thread::detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) releases ownership - when the `shared_ptr` is destroyed nothing will happen to the detached thread of execution.

This is bad practice because you could simply write...

```
std::thread{[]{ std::cout<< "HelloWorld" << std::endl; }}.detach();
```

...to spawn a background thread that cleans up after itself.

Comment: Obviously, OP has provided an mcve, in their actual implementation, there might be details which justify the usage of a smart pointer. (+1 anyway)

Comment: Note that detached threads make a program nearly impossible to prove correct, as detecting that your thread has actually completed before main ends is next to impossible without platform specific hacks after it has detached.  And threads running after main ends is not portable, to say the least.

Comment: @Yakk Or maybe main doesn't return at all (and you don't `exit` either).